# Python3 how to read a file delimited by spaces which length varies

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I would like to make a Python3 code using `csv.reader`.

This is an example file to read.

```
#hoge.txt
a b c d  e f    g
a    b c d  e   f    g
a b c   d  e f    g
a  b   c   d e    f  g
```

I want to have arrays like this

```
[[a,a,a,a],[b,b,b,b],[c,c,c,c]...[g,g,g,g]]
```

(The number of elements is fixed.)

My current code is

```
from csv import reader
with open('hoge.txt') as f:
    data = reader(f, delimiter=' ')
```

But, apparently, it doesn't work. 
How can I make it as if

```
    data = reader(f, delimiter='\s+')
```

Comment: Can you use `pandas`

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('hoge.txt', 'r') as fin:
    data=[line.split() for line in fin]
```

this will give the output like

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], 
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']]
```

but since your desired output is different so

```
list1 = []
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    list1.append([x[i] for x in data])
```

this will produce

```
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['d', 'd', 'd', 'd']]
```

I hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've got CSV? Your example file is space-delimited, and my first approach is to use split(). Something like this:

```
allcols = []
with open("hoge.txt", "r") as f:
    vals = f.read().split()
    for i, el in enumerate(vals):
        allcols[i].append(el)
```

If you really do have CSV but with extraneous spaces, then I'd still go with per-line processing, but like this:

```
from csv import reader
data = ""
with open("hoge.txt", "r") as f:
    newline = f.read().strip(" ")
    data.append(reader(newline))
```

hth